# AEM 6.3 Unlock page using impersonation gives error

Tags: java, aem, impersonation, unlock

In AEM 6.3 When impersonating a user to open his locked page and try to unlock gives 500 error.

The post /bin/wcmcommand triggered for the unlock gives 500 error.

the canUnlock method returns true,
the lockOwner is same as currentUserID.

This seems to be a bug with AEM 6.3

Do we know if there is a workaround or a fix for this.

Reference https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2394206

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by invoking custom sling servlet to unlock/lock for impersonators in AEM 6.3.1.2 from siteadmn.actions.js